# Registering Routes to Central Object in Go

Tags: rest, go, gorilla

I'm working on a simple Go REST API, using Mux. Most of the tutorials I've found suggested creating the router as follows:

- A `routes.go` file which contains a global array of all routes and all route handlers.
- A `router.go` file which creates a router object and loops over the global array and registers everything to the router.

I'd rather use a different model:

- A `router.go` file instantiates a router object and has a `RegisterRoute` function
- Each file, representing a different object or component of the API, can call `RegisterRoute` and add additional routes to the router.

I have no idea how to do this, because it seems to require creating an initialization function for each file and calling it from `main()` (which defeats the purpose). Is there any accepted way to do this?

Comment: Well, if (and that I'm not sure) I understand your problem, then `func init()` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `func init()`. It is a special function which is called right before program execution, during package initialization.

Here is an example of how to achieve what you want using gorilla/mux router, though it can be achieved with any other mux library.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

// main.go

type Route struct {
    Name        string
    Method      string
    Pattern     string
    HandlerFunc http.HandlerFunc
}

var routes []Route

func registerRoute(route Route) {
    routes = append(routes, route)
}

func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(false)
    for _, route := range routes {
        router.
            Methods(route.Method).
            Path(route.Pattern).
            Name(route.Name).
            Handler(route.HandlerFunc)
    }

    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}

// index.go
func init() {
    registerRoute(Route{
        "index",
        "GET",
        "/",
        func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "welcome")
        },
    })
}

// users.go
func init() {
    registerRoute(Route{
        "listUsers",
        "GET",
        "/users",
        listUsers,
    })
}

func listUsers(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "users list")
}

// products.go
func init() {
    registerRoute(Route{
        "listProducts",
        "GET",
        "/products",
        listProducts,
    })
}

func listProducts(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "products list")
}
```

This pattern is used by golang for example by `database/sql` and `image` packages. You can read a little bit more about this here: https://www.calhoun.io/why-we-import-packages-we-dont-actually-use-in-golang/